# How To Send Invoice Of Succeeded Card Payment?

Tags: javascript, invoice, stripe-payments

So far I've made a payment system with stripe. I collect card data, shipping data and billing data. First I create a payment intent on the nodejs backend then I confirm the card payment on the react frontend. But what I want to do is sending invoices to customer. When I read the stripe docs, they were talking about paying invoices. Now my customer already paid with the card information (In stripe dashboard in the payments section the payments are marked as succeeded) I just only want to send them an invoice without forcing them to pay. For to do that, should I create an invoice then set it's status to paid then send the customer as email? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

PaymentIntents are different to Invoices. If you want Stripe to automatically send emails to your users, you'd use Invoicing instead: https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/sending